# TTL: wait for dynamically generated string

Tags: teraterm

I'm scripting an automation in TTL.

I have a parameter that is determined by the object I'm connecting to, so I parse it into a variable named `pos`. This part of the code is more than fine.

Now, I'd like to wait for a textual string like

```
wait 'A 'pos' B'
```

Note that in the string I'm waiting for, the variable `pos` is part of the string. This syntax isn't working because, according to [docs](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/en/macro/command/wait.html) this is waiting on either `A` or `pos` or `B`.

e.g. if `pos=3` i'd like to `wait 'A 3 B'` as a whole, not as alternative. I can't find in the docs the correct syntax to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put multiple strings, create a service variable and populate it,

```
msg = ''
strconcat msg 'A '
strconcat msg pos
strconcat msg ' B'
wait msg
```

see [strconcat](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/en/macro/command/strconcat.html)